# Mockito: mock injected member of newly generated object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to test the following class:

```
public class ClassToTest {
    private List<Bar> bars = new LinkedList<>();

    public makeBarsFromIDs(List<Integer> idList) {
        for (Integer id : idList) {
            Bar bar = new Bar();
            bar.setID(id);
            bars.add(bar);
        }
    }

    public List<String> getFooStringsFromBars() {
        List<String> fooStrings = new LinkedList();
        for (Bar bar : this.bars)
            fooStrings.add(bar.getFooListAsString());
        return fooStrings;
    }
}
```

In addToBarList, a `Bar` object is instanciated.

```
public class Bar {
    private int myID;

    @Inject
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    public setID(int ID) {
        myID = ID;
    }

    public String getFooListAsString() {
        return fooRepository.findByID(myID).toString();
    }
}
```

Bar uses `FooRepository`, which I want to mock. This works fine if I test `Bar`, but how can I test `ClassToTest` and still mock `FooRepository`?

I cannot just mock `Bar`, since multiple instances with different values are created. And I need to test whether they are created correctly.

Comment: If you want to mock `Bar` then you can't do `Bar bar = new Bar();` within the method. If you are using a framework like Spring then inject `Bar` as a dependency and then mock it out.

Comment: I don't want to mock Bar, I want to mock fooRepository inside Bar.

Comment: I stripped my sample code down a little too much. The thing is, `ClassToTest` creates multiple 'Bar' objects inside a loop. How would I mock them? I thought maybe some extension like PowerMock can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to mock `FooRepository` if you are testing `ClassToTest` as it will serve as a Black-Box for this class. All you should do is mock out the `Bar` and write the test.

But before doing that you'll have to start injecting `Bar` as a dependecy in your `ClassToTest` in the same way as you did it for `FooRepository` in case of `Bar`.

This is because if you have following statement in your method then a new onject will be create for `Bar` and there is no way you can replace it with your mock.

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
```

After making the relevant changes, your `ClassToTest` should look like this:

```
public class ClassToTest {

    @Inject
    private Bar bar;

    public addToBarList(barID) {
        bar.setID(fooID);

        List<Foo> fooList = bar.getFooList();
        ...
    }
}
```

Your test class should look like this:

```
public class SomeTest {

    @Mock
    private Bar bar;

    @InjectMocks
    private ClassToTest testClass;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        Mockito.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        Mockito.when(bar.getFooList()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(new Foo()));
        testClass.addToBarList(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: As I wrote in my last comment, my sample code was stripped down little too much. What I actually have is a `Collection` of `Bar`, which is filled by `ClassToTest`.

Comment: @user2727133 Sometimes you have to re-think your design in order to effectively use frameworks like `Mockito`. Please include the missing code and then maybe I can help you better.

Comment: I edited my code now. Thank you very much for your effort.